# Doctrine mongo ODM duplicating embedded documents in Symfony

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine, phpunit, doctrine-odm

Using Doctrine mongo ODM 1.0.0-BETA8 in Symfony 2.2.1, I'm running into troubles with the update portion of CRUD.  Upon `persist()` the new embedded documents are being duplicated.

I ran the phpunit tests relating to embedded documents that come with doctrine-odm and they seem to work fine.  One thing that I noticed that is different between the Doctrine test documents and my documents is the presence of an id in the embedded document.  As far as I see, an id in a sub document is unnecessary and this is evidenced by the Documents in the test suite User and Phonenumber.  Phonenumber doesn't have an id and the tests pass.

I am generating my documents from yaml like so:

```
App\AppBundle\Document\Lexicon:
    db: somedb
    collection: somecollection
    fields:
      id:
        type: id
        id: true
      interpretations:
        embedded: true
        type: many
        targetDocument: App\AppBundle\Document\Interpretation

App\AppBundle\Document\Interpretation:
  type: embeddedDocument #this looks like a good thing to do
  fields:
    #id:    #when this is commented out, Symfony throws an error
    #  type: id
    #  id: true
    explanation: 
      type: string
```

I don't want an Interpretation id, but without it symfony complains **No identifier/primary key specified for Document**.  Though I suspect that somehow this is causing the problem.

```
    $entity = $dm->getRepository('App\AppBundle\Document\Lexicon')->find($id);

    $int = new Interpretation(); 
    $int->setExplanation('first'); 
    $entity->addInterpretation($int);

    $dm->persist($entity);
    $dm->flush();
```

And this results in Lexicon having 2 Interpretations:

```
{
  "explanation": "first"
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("517d8040cbad49f001000004"),
  "explanation": "first"
}
```

EDIT: I found the `type: embeddedDocument` directive to replace the `id` stanza.  Remembered to sync everything up with:

```
php app/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents AppAppBundle 
php app/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:hydrators
```

However there still seeing duplication.